# TemplateRef<any> or TemplateRef<Element>

Tags: angular

I have a couple of templates I need to reference.

```
<ng-template #tmp>...
```

What is the better approach?

```
@ViewChild('tmp') tmp: TemplateRef<Element>;
@ViewChild('tmp') tmp: TemplateRef<any>;
```

I general I try to avoid any. But I'm not sure if Element is the correct type. On  the other hand I saw a ton of examples with TemplateRef.

Comment: What about looking into the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef) to see what the generic type of `TemplateRef` means?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `TemplateRef<any>`,
It's good to avoid any, but in this case might be better to stick to that.

Angular itself uses any

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2f9a59a24c0464cbed7f54cbeb5cba73e6007715/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/bottom-sheet-harness/bottom-sheet-harness-example.ts#L11

I don't think Element is correct here. You can try to print the `TemplateRef` to see what's inside. You could if you want add types but except if you actually change or manipulate those TemplateRef, you can stick to `any` for ease. Otherwise, if you really want some types you need to create a Context ( as suggested in the doc or the code )

This is how it would look like https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2f9a59a24c0464cbed7f54cbeb5cba73e6007715/src/material/stepper/stepper-icon.ts#L13

Hope this helps

Comment: Any explanation why? Because you found it somewhere in Angular source code is not a good reason.

Comment: let me rephrase